# How to make 3-D graph in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following object.

```
var x = [{
"time": 8,
"projects": "creat"
       }, {
"time": 6,
"projects": "tracker"
       }, {
"time": 2,
"projects": "study"
    }]
```

i want to make 3D graph(pie), in it the time should show in the corresponded area of the pie graph,and when i click on a particular area, that part should pop up from the pie chart. 
And the color of each section should be different.
Can any one could do it fiddle or code pen?

Comment: Could u please post more js code?

Comment: you can visit http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Creating a fresh Ionic Framework project-

```
ionic start IonicProject blank
cd IonicProject
ionic platform add android
ionic platform add ios
```

Then- **www/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-chart.css">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>

        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-pane>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
                <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then ** www/js/app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'chart.js'])
```

Next, drop down lower into the file and create a new controller called ExampleController with the following code (in **www/js/app.js**):

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];

});
```

Going back into the **www/index.html** file, find the `<ion-content>` tags and replace them with the following:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            A line chart
        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" series="series" options="{showTooltips: false}"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            A bar chart
        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" series="series" options="{showTooltips: false}"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Then u will get your desired output like this-

[image]

And this-

[image]

Think, u have your answer :).

---

### Update-

A video tutorial on this topic can be found in [**here in YouTube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FsKXoA0ZdU).